# Help explore parametric system in SageMath

Tags: parametric, sagemath

i could use some help in presenting a good solution for this problem :
**Problem**
Assume the system of equations in $x, y, z, t$
$ax+y+z+t=1$
$x+ay+z+t=b$
$x+y+az+t=b^2$
$x+y+z+at=b^3$
where $a, b$ are integer parameters. Determine the values of $a$ and $b$ for which the system has infinitely many solutions and the values of $a$ and $b$ for which the system has no solutions.

I have solved the equations and then for the values of $a$ that make the denominator equal to zero, i solved the numerators for $b$. I found the pairs of $a$ and $b$ that make the system impossible, or to have infinite solutions but i was wondering if there is a more "programming" way in SageMath.
Thank you in advance.

**Edit 1:** I 've gone so far but now i can't manage to extract my last columns and create equations $= 0$ to solve as $b$.

[my solution so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqXFn.png)

I am trying to create the equations [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a9xX.png) but it returns False, False, False.

 What is the difference with [that way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYgaR.png) of creating equations?

Comment: I understand that you wanted to see how you could use Sagemath for this problem. But have you noticed that this issue can be solved very easily "by hand" by adding your 4 equations which gives you $x+y+z+t=$ something ?Subtracting this equation to each other one gives at once the "values" of $x,y,z,t$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second way of solving the problem looks promising, from Sagemath's point of view.

```
sage: var('t x y z')
(t, x, y, z)
sage: var('a b', domain=ZZ)
(a, b)
sage: eq = [a*x + y + z + t == 1, x + a*y + z + t == b, x + y + a*z + t == b^2, x + y + z + a*t == b^3]
sage: solve(eq, x, y, z, t)
[[x == -(b^3 + b^2 - a + b - 2)/(a^2 + 2*a - 3), y == -(b^3 - a*b + b^2 - 2*b + 1)/(a^2 + 2*a - 3), z == (a*b^2 - b^3 + 2*b^2 - b - 1)/(a^2 + 2*a - 3), t == (a*b^3 + 2*b^3 - b^2 - b - 1)/(a^2 + 2*a - 3)]]
```

You should be able to answer your questions from here.